# What is the procedure to add domain aliases to an existing linux apache installation?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost, vps

I have a personal VPS hosted in *** and an ubuntu installation. The ubuntu runs apache,php,mysql and is currently being used for 5 websites mapped by virtualhosts. I am writing the whole procedure in case someone needs it.

When I want to add a new domain, I create an `127.0.0.1 test.com *.test.com` row in `/etc/hosts`, add a new file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and `run a2ensite test.com` - then restart apache. Each website has its own folder in `/var/www` and the virtualhost entry looks like this :

```
<Virtualhost *:80>

      # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
      ServerAdmin info@test.com
      ServerName  www.test.com
      ServerAlias test.com *.test.com

      # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
      DocumentRoot "/var/www/test.com"
      <Directory /var/www/test.com>
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
      </Directory>  
</Virtualhost>
```

I am planning to add some aliases like `aaa.test.com`, `bbb.test.com`, `ccc.test.com` etc. which will point/forward to different folders. The `aaa.test.com` one will point to `/var/www/aaa/index.php` and the `bbb.test.com` to `/var/www/bbb/index.php`. To summarize, different aliases - same domain - different folders all in apache. How do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As aaa.test.com and bbb.test.com should point to different directories, You are required to create separate Virtualhost entries manually. Before that you have to remove the _*.test.com_ from the *ServerAlias* of test.com *Virtualhost* entry. Then create a file at */etc/apache2/sites-available* , say *aaa.test.com* and add the following and then save

```
<Virtualhost *:80>

  ServerName  aaa.test.com
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/aaa/"

</Virtualhost>
```

make sure to restart/reload the apache service.

Do the same for bbb.test.com.. That is all you required to do...  All d best :)

Comment: what about the nameservers? do I add a cname for aaa ?

Comment: The nameservers and cname records are related with DNS and no relation with the apache webserver. It depends on where this domain registered and how it should resolve. Also name servers are always adding for the main domain and not for the sub domain. Let me know your exact requirement with DNS, so that I might be able to help you. :)

Comment: I guess to completely setup a new domain you'll have to create an A record that points to the DNS host. thanks

Comment: Yes, Exactly you need...and however apache has no relation with setting up DNS.

Answer (score 2):

There can only exist one `DocumentRoot` per `VirtualHost` container. Since you have specified different `DocumentRoot` for each `aaa.test.com`, `bbb.test.com` etc, you need to setup a separate `VirtualHost` for each:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName aaa.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/aaa
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

and so on.

Comment: That is it... Greb :)